# Call a function until one of its outputs meets constraint (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

I have a function `multirun` with 3 inputs, as seen below. If I call/run it **n** times, the output for **run number n** goes into a file named `output_n.txt`.

Below is the code I have now written calling the function.

```
CO2 = [0.00007, 0.00008, 0.00009]
H2O = [0.00003, 0.000035, 0.00004]
FO2 = [-2,-1,0,1,2]


for i in CO2:
    for j in H2O:
        for k in FO2:
            multirun( WTCO2_START = [i], WTH2O_START = [j], FO2_buffer_START= [k])
```

I want it to run through **all combinations** of the 3 inputs, until the output results in a run `output_n.txt` meet certain constraints. My constraint is for example, one of the numbers in `output_n.txt` to equal another number in a different file `constrain.txt`

My issues are:
1. My code above only produces `output_0.txt` even though it is run for all combinations of the 3 numbers.
2. I don't know how to set the constraint

Comment: You might have to consider adding your code, so that we can understand your question better.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma added!

Comment: Sorry, that was a silly answer (so I deleted it). Use `pdb` or add some `print` statements around file creation to debug this situation. Good luck! (also `**kwargs` is as eveil as `void*` in C)

Comment: Above code has no output at all. So are you asking about output or loop termination or...? More clarity needed there! Why did you edit out the code again of the function doing the output?